# Help with Deriving the Euler-Lagrange equation(Possible misunderstanding Leibniz integral rule)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-explanation, euler-lagrange-equation

I have been working on the euler lagrange equations for physics, and they very briefly discussed the build up of it. I want to know more about it so I started to use wiki for help but I am stuck on this step (below) [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation)

\begin{equation}
\frac{dJ_\varepsilon}{d\varepsilon} = \int_a^b\left[\eta(x)\frac{\partial L_\varepsilon}{\partial f_\varepsilon} +\eta'(x) \frac{\partial L_\varepsilon}{\partial f'_\varepsilon}\right] dx
\end{equation}

When $\varepsilon = 0$, then $g_\varepsilon = f$ and (etc).<<< I understand this.

A step inbetween could be:
\begin{equation}
\left.\frac{dJ_\varepsilon}{d\varepsilon}\right|_{\varepsilon = 0} = \int_a^b\left.\left[\eta(x)\frac{\partial L_\varepsilon}{\partial f_\varepsilon} +\eta'(x) \frac{\partial L_\varepsilon}{\partial f'_\varepsilon}\right]\right|_{\varepsilon=0} dx =0
\end{equation}

Then (need help on this step)

\begin{equation}
\left.\frac{dJ_\varepsilon}{d\varepsilon}\right|_{\varepsilon = 0} = \int_a^b\left[\eta(x)\frac{\partial L}{\partial g} +\eta'(x) \frac{\partial L}{\partial g'}\right] dx = 0
\end{equation}

**My question** is, How did we apply the $\varepsilon = 0$ before actually solving this $\left[\eta(x)\frac{\partial L_\varepsilon}{\partial f_\varepsilon} +\eta'(x) \frac{\partial L_\varepsilon}{\partial f'_\varepsilon}\right]$ ?

Example:

let $y(x,\alpha) =x + \alpha $

then $k_1 = \frac{\partial y}{\partial \alpha} = 1$ now setting $\alpha = 0$, $k = 1$

but letting $\alpha = 0$ first, we get $y(x,0) =x$

then $k_2 = \frac{\partial y}{\partial \alpha} = 0$

thus $k_1 \neq k_2$ and so order matters

So clearly I am not understanding this. I tried looking for more information on this step (leibniz integral rule [here](https://www.open.edu/openlearn/pluginfile.php/1118521/mod_resource/content/3/Introduction%20to%20the%20calculus%20of%20variations_ms327.pdf) , page 21), but its still not clear.

I would be very greatful if you could expand apon the step.

Comment: It’s because of the horrid notation being used on wiki. Write $L=L(x,u,v)$ and write $\partial L/\partial u$, etc., then evaluate at $u=f_\epsilon$, $v=f’_\epsilon$, then set $\epsilon=0$.

Comment: @TedShifrin , thank you for your reply. I tried what you suggested,$\int_a^b\left.\left[\eta(x)\frac{\partial L}{\partial u} +\eta'(x) \frac{\partial L}{\partial v}\right]\right|_{\varepsilon = 0} dx$, but I am still not understanding it. It still feels like we are setting the $\varepsilon = 0$ before working the partial derivatives. Is it becuase the $L$ does not explicitly have the $\varepsilon$?

Comment: No, you not evaluate at $\epsilon=0$ until after you differentiate. When you do $df/dx\big| _{x=0}$, you differentiate, then evaluate. In this case , $L$ doesn’t know what $\epsilon$ is.

Comment: To make sense of this, put the argument in and write $\frac{\partial L}{\partial u}(x,f_\epsilon(x),f’_\epsilon(x))$, etc.

Comment: @TedShifrin , Thanks again. Just to confirm, becuase $L$ is not explicitly expressed with $\varepsilon$ ("doesn’t know what ϵ is"), we can let $\varepsilon = 0$ immediately after writing out $\left[\eta(x)\frac{\partial L_\varepsilon}{\partial f_\varepsilon} +\eta'(x) \frac{\partial L_\varepsilon}{\partial f'_\varepsilon}\right]$ as $L$ would have noticed any explicit change, and thus the partials would be the same as if we did not change $\varepsilon$?

Comment: Crossposted to https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/737199/2451